# json curly brackets displaying in Div that display the json result

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery script that does a lookup on a data table and returns a result.

However, when I display the result inside a DIV the curly brackets surrounding the json data are also displayed. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#board').change(function(){
    $.get('check_override_image.php', { RecordID: form2.board.value },
    function(result) {
        $('#size').html(result).show();
    });
});
});
```

The Json result is:

```
{"imagesizes":[{"DisplayWidth":"1080","DisplayHeight":"1920"}]}
```

I am displaying the result using

```
<div id="size"></div>
```

What I want to display is DisplayWidth:1080,DisplayHeight:1920 removing all the brackets and quote marks.

Is this possible.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JSON.parse()` then access keys, values normally.

See below example:

```
result = JSON.parse(result);
$('#size').html("DisplayWidth: " + result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayWidth"] 
            + ", DisplayWidth: " + result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayWidth"]).show();
```

Comment: Many thanks that did the trick. I will now study your code and try to learn from it. Many thanks. And thanks to others who replied.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to remove parts of the object manually then

```js
var result = {"imagesizes":[{"DisplayWidth":"1080","DisplayHeight":"1920"}]};

var html   = Object.keys( result.imagesizes[0] ).map(function(key) {
 return key + ':' + result.imagesizes[0][key];
}).join(', ');

$('#size').html(html).show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="size"></div>
```

If the ajax call returns the correct headers, the result would already be parsed as an object, otherwise you'd have JSON, and need `JSON.parse`, something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#board').change(function(){
        $.get('check_override_image.php', {RecordID:form2.board.value}, function(json) {
            var result = JSON.parse(json);
            var html   = Object.keys( result.imagesizes[0] ).map(function(key) {
                return key + ':' + result.imagesizes[0][key];
            }).join(', ');

            $('#size').html(html).show();
        });
    });
});
```